# Android EditText doesn't show keyboard hint if use more than one inputType attribute

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I'm trying to have an Edit text with keyboard hints and auotcorrection for words (such as when you write a message in whatsapp).

This is my code:

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:hint="@string/note_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text" />
```

According with the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) it should work but it doesn't.
I've also tried using the deprecated  `android:autoText="true"`.

I need all the functionallity specified in the InputType

**Edit:**

After some try I discovered that if I set only one attribute without problem but if I set all of what I need nothing work correctly.

**Edit 2:**

What I want to obtain is something like the Whatsapp editbox where you write your message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with the input type, have you tried single combinations?

Using a combination of textAutoCorrect and textAutoComplete might not always work

Comment: Just tried with only textAutoComplete and it seems to work correctly

Comment: Sorry but It Must be Multiline EditText

Comment: android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"

Comment: @MatteoCorti it might sound silly but is autoCorrect enabled in your device settings? Have you tweaked any system settings?

Comment: Yes it's enabled because in oter applcation (not mine) it works